# javascript array gets updated when I update another array

Tags: javascript

```
function setobjprop(ind, prop, v) {
    if (undo_arr.length > 0) {
        console.log("C" + undo_arr.length + ": " + undo_arr[0][0].rotate);
    }
    console.log(ind + ":" + prop + ":" + v);
    user_img[ind][prop] = v;
    if (undo_arr.length > 0) {
        console.log("D" + undo_arr.length + ": " + undo_arr[0][0].rotate);
    }
    undo_arr.push(user_img.slice(0));
    console.log(undo_arr[0][0].rotate);
    console.log(prop + " -> " + v);
    if (undo_arr.length > 10) {
        undo_arr.shift();
    }
    redrawCanvas(ind);
}
```

I have an array of objects called `user_img`, now I wrote a function to update the value of an object at a particular index within this array, then I am trying to store a copy of this entire array in another array called `undo_arr`. But all copies of the array in the undo_arr seems to point to the `user_img` array, because the object modification seems to reflect upon all copies previously stored in the `undo_arr`. Any idea what I am doing wrong?

Comment: You are not creating a copy of the array. You simply add a reference to it. If you want to create a deep copy (i.e. copy the array and the objects it contains) have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/q/122102.

Comment: When you assign a variable (or array element) to a variable that references an object, you end up with two references to the same object.

Comment: but shouldn't slice(0) copy a new version of the array over? If not How can I copy it?

Comment: You didn't have `.slice` before in your code ;) It only creates a shallow copy, not a deep one, i.e. the objects the array contains are not cloned. See the link in my first comment. Especially this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/122190. You probably want `undo_arr.push(clone(img_arr));`.